Is the following min min max min problem equivalent to a min max min problem?
I am currently working with a traditional two stage min-max-min robust optimization problem like this
$$\begin{aligned}&\min_\mathbf{y}\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{y}+\max_{u\in\mathcal{U}}\min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{y},u)}\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}\\&\mathrm{s.t.~}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}\geq\mathbf{d},\quad\mathbf{y}\in\mathbf{S}_\mathbf{y}\end{aligned}$$
I know that this problem can be addresses by column and constraint generation algorithm. If the uncertainty set $\mathcal{U}$ is variable, take the conventional budget-constrained uncertainty sets as an example
$$\begin{aligned}
&u_{ih}=\hat{u}_{ih}+\Delta_{ih}^+z_{ih}^+-\Delta_{ih}^-z_{ih}^-&& \forall i\in\mathcal{R},\quad\forall h\in\mathcal{H} \\
&0\leq z_{ih}^{+},z_{ih}^{-}\leq1\quad\forall i\in\mathcal{R},&& \forall h\in\mathcal{H} \\
&\sum_{i\in\mathcal{R}}z_{ih}^++z_{ih}^-\leq\Gamma|\mathcal{R}|&& \forall h\in\mathcal{H} \\
&\sum_{h\in\mathcal{H}}z_{ih}^{+}+z_{ih}^{-}\leq\Lambda && \forall i\in\mathcal{R}. 
\end{aligned}$$
In the above uncertainty set, assume $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ are both variables, the problem I want to solve becomes
$$\begin{aligned}&\min_\mathbf{y}\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{y}+\min_{\Gamma,\Lambda}\max_{u\in\mathcal{U}(\Gamma,\Lambda)}\min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{y},u)}\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}\\
&\mathrm{s.t.~}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}\geq\mathbf{d},\quad\mathbf{y}\in\mathbf{S}_\mathbf{y}\\
& \quad\quad h(\Gamma,\Lambda)\leq 0 \end{aligned}$$
Is the above problem equal to
$$\begin{aligned}&\min_{\mathbf{y},\Gamma,\Lambda}\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{y}+\max_{u\in\mathcal{U}(\Gamma,\Lambda)}\min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{y},u)}\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}\\
&\mathrm{s.t.~}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}\geq\mathbf{d},\quad\mathbf{y}\in\mathbf{S}_\mathbf{y}\\
& \quad\quad h(\Gamma,\Lambda)\leq 0 \end{aligned}$$
